# How to dynamically specify which linked server to address in a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, linked-server

From our SQL Server I can execute the following code to executed a procedure on an Oracle server connected as a linked server to get some data:

```
EXEC ('BEGIN Get_Data(?,?,?,?);
        END;', 
        @Id, 
        @Status OUTPUT,
        @Customer OUTPUT,
        @Name OUTPUT ) at OraTestServer;
```

*OraTestServer* is the defined name of the linked server. Now I want to use dynamically different linked server, how can I accomplish that?

I already tried the following, but that isn't working:

```
EXEC('EXEC (''BEGIN Get_Data(?,?,?,?);
            END;'', 
            @Id, 
            @Status OUTPUT,
            @Customer OUTPUT,
            @Name OUTPUT ) at '+ @LinkedServer + ';')
```

Comment: you put the parameters inside the dynamic sql

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: @manderson I can't even get sp_executesql working even by not trying to use a dynamic linked server. How would the first call look like with sp_executesql ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
EXEC (
'EXEC (''BEGIN Get_Data(?,?,?,?);
        END;'', '+
        @Id+','+
        @Status+ ' OUTPUT,'+
        @Customer+ ' OUTPUT,'+
        @Name+ ' OUTPUT ) at ' +@LinkedServer
)
```

Comment: string concatenation may not 100% correct, but what you need to do is to put parameters out of the string concatenation, otherwise, the sql executes this as string such as `@parameter` instead of real value you assigned to @parameter

Comment: I tried it but that solution didn't work.That is the big question how to execute it and still being able to get the output '@parameter' filled.

Comment: Try to declare `@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)` and set everything within the outer `EXEC` to @SQL, try to `print (@SQL)`, check the result whether that is the correct query